# StringBuilder AppendFormat with @

Tags: c#

Is it possible to somehow do this without taking out the @?  It does not like @

```
    cJavaScript.AppendFormat(@"

            function GetNextProductIDs(state) 
            {

                var productIDs = new Array();

                var {0}lastProductFoundIndex = $.inArray({0}lastProductID, {0}allProductIDs);
                return productIDs.join();
            }; ", ClientID);
```

Comment: what do you mean, "It does not like @"?

Comment: What's wrong with having the format string in resources? Then at least you won't have to escape double quotes. The curly braces still have to be escaped, but that can be done by a loading function.

Comment: Oregon Ghost, what do you mean by format string in resources?

Comment: Oregon, can you let me know what you meant by that?  Just for my info.

Comment: Sorry, somehow I didn't recognize that there's a comment. I meant using resource files (i.e. .resx/.resources). You should be doing that anyway for any strings in the application. And there's nothing wrong with putting this kind of "technical" string (i.e. not for user's eyes) into resources as well. Makes handling all these things so much easier. If you still don't know what I mean, look into the Resources.resx automatically generated by Visual Studio, or add a new resource file in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is not with the @, but with the curly brace. Using two curly braces will escape them propertly.

```
cJavaScript.AppendFormat(@"
        function GetNextProductIDs(state) 
        {{

            var productIDs = new Array();

            var {0}lastProductFoundIndex = $.inArray({0}lastProductID, {0}allProductIDs);
            return productIDs.join();
        }}; ", ClientID);
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use use string.Concat or StringBuilder to append multi-line strings like this together. Usually I don't really care if the cr/lf's are in there, but you can adjust if you do:

```
string fmt = string.Concat(
    "function GetNextProductIDs(state) ",
    "{",
        "var productIDs = new Array();"
    ...
    );
cJavaScript.AppendFormat(fmt, ClientID);
```

Comment: No need to use a string builder when the strings are constants. The C# compiler uses constant folding to concatenate them into a single string at compile time.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add that using a string builder is normally recommended for performance reasons, to avoid string copying when concatenating several strings. However, in this scenario, using a string builder or Concat is actually less performant and also generates more code.

Comment: I want to keep the format..but probably not possible unless shoved into a .js

Comment: And I'm going to be appending multiple sections like this.  There is a good amount of javascript.

Comment: cr/lf's  -  Sorry, I am bad with acronyms.  What do you mean by that?

Comment: The strings are constant, so for example concatenating "fu"+"bar" is done by the compiler at compile time, resulting in the constant "fubar" being emitted into the resulting IL code. There's no runtime overhead.

Answer (score 0):

All the "@" is doing is honouring the line breaks. You can remove the "@" by replacing the line breaks with "\r\n":

```
cJavaScript.AppendFormat(
        "function GetNextProductIDs(state)\r\n" +
        "{\r\n\r\n" +
        "    var productIDs = new Array();\r\n\r\n" +
        "    var {0}lastProductFoundIndex = $.inArray({0}lastProductID, {0}allProductIDs);\r\n" +
        "    return productIDs.join();\r\n" +
        "}; ", ClientID);
```

Comment: it also keeps you from having to escape " which I like and I will have in some of my JavaScript (I just didn't post the entire thing here for you to see that). I don't like having to escape things if I don't have to, just more code and readability pains

Comment: I also wonder if doing all those + defeats the purpose of using a StringBuilder in the first place

Comment: The compiler will concatenate the string constants at compile time, so there would be no effect on run time performance.

Comment: then I guess you're saying if you use + in a StringBuilder it's not like using + to concatenate which would reduce performance...that StringBuilder knows how to handle + better if you need to be adding + in an Append method?

Comment: I just don't like the feeling of using + with any StringBuilder method.  Makes me feel like I'm dirty and coding inefficient because at that point you might as well just do this: string a = "some text" + "some more text" + ..

Comment: It has nothing to do with StringBuilder or any other class or method.  If you have 2 string literals separated by a '+' operator the compiler will concatenate them at compile time.

Comment: You still have to escape " when using @, just that it's escaped as a double "" instead of \"

Answer (score 0):

The `StringBuilder`'s `AppendFormat` method takes a format string. Because the string you are using contains `{` and `}` as the JavaScript method curly braces, it is interpreting the method as a format token.

To escape them, use double curly braces `{{` and `}}`.